# split a series into multiple pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, one of the columns has a series in there. The structure is as follows:

```
Date          Col1
2022-01-02    'Amt_Mean                 2022.0\nAmt_Med                   5.0\nAmt_Std     877.0\ndtype: float64'


2022-01-03    'Amt_Mean                 2025.0\nAmt_Med                   75.0\nAmt_Std     27.0\ndtype: float64'
```

I want to reshape this such that I get the following output

```
Date        Amt_Mean   Amt_Med   Amt_Std
2022-01-02  2022.0     5.0       877.0
2022-01-03  2025.0     75.0      27.0
```

How can I achieve this? I tried `df['Col1'][0][1]` which gives me the first amount and I can potentially for loop it, but seems there should be a more easy (pythonic) way of doing this.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a dict version of your df?

Comment: @richardec doing a ````df.to_dict(orient='records')```` results in    ````[{'Date':'2022-01-02', 'Col1': 'Amt_Mean                 2022.0\nAmt_Med                   5.0\nAmt_Std     877.0\ndtype: float64'}, {'Date':'2022-01-03', 'Col1':'Amt_Mean                 2025.0\nAmt_Med                   75.0\nAmt_Std     27.0\ndtype: float64'}]````

Comment: You should definitely work on why you have stringified pd.Series objects stored in your `df` in the first place. Sounds like an XY problem to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some string processing to convert each string into a dict, convert those to a dataframe, and concatenate that with the original:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame([dict(re.split(r'\s+', y) for y in x.split('\n')[:-1]) for x in df['Col1']])
df = pd.concat([df.drop('Col1', axis=1), new_df], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
         Date Amt_Mean Amt_Med Amt_Std
0  2022-01-02   2022.0     5.0   877.0
1  2022-01-03   2025.0    75.0    27.0
```

Comment: Seems like they're not strings, but `pd.Series` objects.

Comment: @rafaelc They're Series objects converted to strings, with, e.g. `str(df.iloc[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `pd.Series` objects, I would concatenate them using a chained `pd.concat`:

```
>>> pd.concat([df.Date, pd.concat([x for x in df.Col1], axis=1).T], axis=1)
```

```
         Date  Amt_Mean  Amt_Med  Amt_Std
0  2022-01-02      2022        5      877
1  2022-01-03      2025       75       27
```

This assumes your data is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'Date':'2022-01-02', 
                    'Col1': pd.Series({'Amt_Mean': 2022, "Amt_Med": 5, "Amt_Std":877})}, 
                   {'Date':'2022-01-03', 
                    'Col1': pd.Series({'Amt_Mean': 2025, "Amt_Med": 75, "Amt_Std":27})
                   }])
```